# Pure lua hashing, RIPEMD160 or SHA2?

Tags: hash, lua, sha2, ripemd

Are there any implementations of these hashing algorithms in pure lua? I've found a couple for MD5 and SHA1 but none for these two which are the ones I'll be needing for a project. In the interests of portability, I need something in pure lua. Anyone know of anything?

Answer (score 0):

Lua's [lmd5](http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/~lhf/ftp/lua/#lmd5) library states: **A message digest library for Lua based on OpenSSL. It supports MD2, MD4, MD5, SHA1, SHA2, RIPEMD160, MDC2.** Though I have never used it. But there are some libraries [listed here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/CryptographyStuff). You might one of them useful.

Here's another [library](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SecureHashAlgorithm) which might be what you seek.

Comment: If its "based on OpenSSL", then its not in pure lua. (Unless based on means inspired by, or in the style of)

Comment: @MichaelAnderson I think [this one](http://lua-users.org/wiki/SecureHashAlgorithm)'s is pure lua implementation

Answer (score 0):

If you use LuaJIT I have written an implementation of SHA256 here but it uses FFI ctypes: https://github.com/catwell/cw-lua/tree/master/sha256

Otherwise there's one here in pure Lua 5.2 which I have not tested: http://lua-users.org/wiki/SecureHashAlgorithm (already cited by Dream Eater).